# How do I switch the Alert Pop-Up View with a custom Alert popup View?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, customization, alert

Im trying create custom AlertView that pops over the home screen as soon as the app opens. Using a custom XIB or View Controller on the story board. I have read up on the UIKit to find a way to switch the alert view for the base to the custom view that I want to present but still no dice.

Here are the custom xibs I want to replace the base AlertView [Custom Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNDyR.png)

My code currently presents the AlertView at the opening of home screen, I just don't know how to switch the base alert view to a custom view

---

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    createAlert(title: "Are you 21 years of Age or Over?", message: "")
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
func createAlert (title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)

    // CREATING ON BUTTON
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Yes")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("No")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly do you want to customize? Are you happy with the general appearance of UIAlertController but just want to change the background & text colors, or do you want to use something different than UIAlertController that essentially does the same job?

Comment: I don't like the general appearance of the UIAlertViewController, I just want to switch it with my own custom view controller so its easier for me to design the custom view to exactly how I want it took like

Comment: Then you can design your own by creating a subclass of UIView and adding text labels and buttons as subviews. I see somebody has already posted an answer on how to do something like that below.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view controller view to your HomeViewController and animate new view like modal present view controller.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var alert: CustomAlertViewController!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Make below code as a seperate method and call from as per your conveience

        alert = CustomAlertViewController(nibName: "CustomAlertViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
        alert.delegate = self
        //animate view like presenting modal view controller
        var rect = alert.view.frame
        rect.origin.y = rect.height
        alert.view.frame = rect

        self.view.addSubview(alert.view)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(0.5)) {
            rect.origin.y = 0
            self.alert.view.frame = rect
        }
    }


}

extension HomeViewController: CustomAlertProtocol {
    func dismissAlert(isYes: Bool) {
        //capture yes no answer from isYes variable

        self.alert.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


}
```

Design your CustomAlertViewController view in nib file as you like.

```
protocol CustomAlertProtocol: class {
    func dismissAlert(isYes: Bool)
}

class CustomAlertViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: CustomAlertProtocol?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    @IBAction func yes(id: Any) {
        delegate?.dismissAlert(isYes: true)
    }

    @IBAction func no(id: Any) {
        delegate?.dismissAlert(isYes: false)
    }


}
```

Comment: seems like it didn't work I'm getting an error in my home view controller on "alert.delegate = self" with error code Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Fatal error is crash not an error. You should be getting fatal error at run time. Can you eleborate more on which action you are getting app crash

Comment: once I run the app, it opens up on the home screen and it crashes in about 5 seconds without showing the custom alert view and brings me back to the HomeVC

Comment: It is clear from the error logs that compiler at run time is not able to find nib file of CustomAlertViewController. Create nib file for this ViewController and design your view according to your need or download it from https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5pvqasj5morapv/CustomAlertViewController.xib?dl=0

Comment: I tested it out and I'm still getting the same errors on the log